# How well does Ubuntu work on Thinkpad X1 Nano with 5G?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, thinkpad, wwan

I am interested in the new ultralight Thinkpad X1 Nano by Lenovo, but I never use Windows. Has anyone tried Ubuntu on it? Does it work well? In particular, does the 5G modem work? What about other basic functions (wifi, audio, touchpad, suspension, etc.)?

Remarks:

1. It has been announced that X1 Nano will come with linux as an option. But I have not found this option available in the online shops of Lenovo.
2. As a reference, Lenovo previously released Thinkpad X1 Carbon with linux (Fedora). However, [the linux edition excludes the LTE modem](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-x1/X1-Carbon-Gen-8-/p/20U9CTO1WWENUS2/customize). Nevertheless, we can always choose the Windows edition, and install linux on it. The [LTE modem does not work out of the box](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/X1-Carbon-8th-Gen-Linux-support/m-p/5015431?page=1#5051982) but there is a [workaround by switching the modem to USB mode](https://github.com/LoreleiAurora/xmm7360_usb).
3. The 5G modem on X1 Nano is "Qualcomm® Snapdragon™ X55 5G Modem M.2 card - RF System with embedded eSIM functionality", as specified in the Lenovo documentation.
4. Since the product is quite new, I expect that maybe nobody has tried Ubuntu on it. It will be nice enough if someone shares some experiences one day later. Any comments or thoughts will also be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: We generally don't do hardware reviews here.

Comment: If hardware does not work file a bug report. We do not accept hardware recommendations.